# WKContentView not key value coding-compliant for key webSelectionAssistant

Tags: ios, webkit, simulator

Does anyone have any idea what might cause this?

```
[<WKContentView 0x7f9c7003f400> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key webSelectionAssistant
```

It happens when you open plain HTML web page (in simulator) inside WKWebView, with text field and type any character on it. Not my code, it's WebKit.

This must be something that's Mac specific, but I have no idea where to start.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You probably use some kind of generic *"All Objective-C Exceptions"* **breakpoint**.

Make sure it's **disabled** during the input.